# SSRS Multi-Value Parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters

I have an SSRS report based on Geographic Locations.  The datasets return project records, with a regional area, electoral area and then a city level.  I have created cascading parameters from region to electoral and then to city.

However, each project can have multiple cities under an electoral region selected.  The user is requesting that the parameter filter *only* records that have that city selected.  So, if the parameter selected are:

- Region: RDEK Region
- Area: City of Cranbrook
- City: (Options are Cranbrook and Rockyview)

If they select *only* "Cranbrook", they want only project records that have *only*Cranbrook selected and not projects that have Cranbrook and Rockyview selected.

Right now my report results will show *all* records with Cranbrook selected and other cities that are selected on the Project.  For example, I would see *all* projects with Cranbrook selected and all projects that have Cranbrook and Rockyview selected.

Below is some more detail of my report.

- Grouped by Regional, Electoral Area and Project Number.
- Parameters :

  - `@Regional` - Available values from Regional Dataset (selecting all available)
  - `@Area` - Available values from Electoral Area Dataset (selecting all available in @Regional)
  - `@City` - Available values from City Dataset (selecting all values in @area)
  - `@Status` - All available statuses
  - `@Fiscal Year` - All available Fiscal years.

I have a Filter on my details Dataset Query (below) that filters only those cities in my `@city` parameter.

My dataset query:

```
SELECT Filteredcbt_geographicarea.cbt_electoralareaidname
  , Filteredcbt_geographicarea.cbt_name AS City
  , Filteredcbt_project.cbt_projectnumber
  , Filteredcbt_geographicarea.cbt_electoralidname
  , Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_committedamount
  , Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_commitmentavailable
  , Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_commitmentdisbursed
  , Filteredcbt_project.cbt_organizationlegalnameidname
  , Filteredcbt_project.statuscodename
  , Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_projectnameid
  , Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_programfiscalyearidname
  , Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_fiscalyearidname
  , Filteredcbt_regionaldistrict.cbt_name AS [Regional District]
FROM Filteredcbt_regionaldistrict
    INNER JOIN Filteredcbt_electoralarea ON Filteredcbt_regionaldistrict.cbt_regionaldistrictid = Filteredcbt_electoralarea.cbt_regionaldistrictid
    INNER JOIN Filteredcbt_category
    INNER JOIN Filteredcbt_program ON Filteredcbt_category.cbt_categoryid = Filteredcbt_program.cbt_categoryid
    INNER JOIN Filteredcbt_project ON Filteredcbt_program.cbt_programid = Filteredcbt_project.cbt_programnameid
    INNER JOIN Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear ON Filteredcbt_project.cbt_projectid = Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_projectnameid
    INNER JOIN Filteredcbt_cbt_project_cbt_geographicarea ON Filteredcbt_project.cbt_projectid = Filteredcbt_cbt_project_cbt_geographicarea.cbt_projectid
    INNER JOIN Filteredcbt_geographicarea ON Filteredcbt_cbt_project_cbt_geographicarea.cbt_geographicareaid = Filteredcbt_geographicarea.cbt_geographicareaid 
        ON Filteredcbt_electoralarea.cbt_electoralareaid = Filteredcbt_geographicarea.cbt_electoralareaid
WHERE        (Filteredcbt_geographicarea.cbt_electoralareaidname IN (@Area)) AND    (Filteredcbt_project.statuscodename IN (@Status)) AND 
                     (Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_fiscalyearidname IN (@FiscalYear)) AND (Filteredcbt_regionaldistrict.cbt_name IN (@Regional)) AND 
                     (Filteredcbt_geographicarea.cbt_name IN (@City)) AND (NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT        cbt_electoralareaid, cbt_electoralareaidname, cbt_electoralid, cbt_electoralidname, cbt_geographicareaid, cbt_name 
                           FROM            Filteredcbt_geographicarea AS ga1
                           WHERE        (cbt_name NOT IN (@City)) AND (cbt_geographicareaid = Filteredcbt_cbt_project_cbt_geographicarea.cbt_geographicareaid)))

ORDER BY Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_fiscalyearidname
ORDER BY Filteredcbt_projectfiscalyear.cbt_fiscalyearidname;
```

Filteredcbt_cbt_project_cbt_geographicarea sample:

```css
cbt_cbt_project_cbt_geographicareaid cbt_geographicareaid                 cbt_projectid
A6D7292F-EA05-E411-BCEA-00155D0470B9 4EB4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193 2C2FC521-EA05-E411                                                                              

998F9FE5-2806-E411-BCEA-00155D0470B9 38B4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193 54FD66DD-2806-E411-

9A8F9FE5-2806-E411-BCEA-00155D0470B9 7EB4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193 54FD66DD-2806-E411-

956F0BD1-2A06-E411-BCEA-00155D0470B9 5BB4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193 82B478C7-2A06-E411-

54D3ED7F-2C06-E411-BCEA-00155D0470B9 54B4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193 ADC83877-2C06-E411-

55D3ED7F-2C06-E411-BCEA-00155D0470B9 C8B4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193 ADC83877-2C06-E411-
EBDC3544-2E06-E411-BCEA-00155D0470B9 5BB4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193 40C1163C-2E06-E411-
70A9B479-AE06-E411-BCEA-00155D0470B9 54B4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193 F24BE26E-AE06-E411-

616C21B3-B506-E411-BCEA-00155D0470B9 65B4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193 C4389EAA-B506-E411-BCEA-
626C21B3-B506-E411-BCEA-00155D0470B9 99B4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193 C4389EAA-B506-E411-BCEA-
636C21B3-B506-E411-BCEA-00155D0470B9 ABB4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193 C4389EAA-B506-E411-BCEA-
646C21B3-B506-E411-BCEA-00155D0470B9 F7B4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193 C4389EAA-B506-E411-BCEA-
```

Filteredcbt_geographicarea sample:

```css
cbt_electoralareaid                     cbt_electoralareaidname cbt_geographicareaid         cbt_name

16B4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193 Town of Creston         2EB4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193     Alice Siding

13B4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193 RDCK Area I             2FB4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193   Thrums

0EB4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193 RDCK Area D             30B4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193   Ainsworth Hot Springs

0EB4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193 RDCK Area D             31B4F611-4BD1-E311-8AB9-00155D067193   Argenta
```

Thank you, let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: This is more of a SQL problem.  You will need to post the query you are using to get your dataset, and probably your table structure as well, in order for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you Tab, I will post more information in my question.

Comment: Thank you Jeroen for editing that post for me!

Comment: I cannot figure this out... Is anyone able to assist?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your WHERE clause:

```
AND NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM Filteredcbt_geographicarea ga1
  WHERE ga1.cbt_name NOT IN (@City)
  AND ga1.cbt_geographicareaid=Filteredcbt_cbt_project_cbt_geographicarea.cbt_geographicareaid 
)
```

If it works, I'll add an explanation to my answer.  : )

Comment: Hi Tab, I added the above to my Where clause on the main dataset, but it did not filter just those in the selection... Projects that have other cities tagged are also showing.

Comment: Ok, it's possible that the data in your tables isn't what I think it is.  Can you edit your question with some sample data from the Filteredcbt_geographicarea table, and also the Filteredcbt_cbt_project_cbt_geographicarea table?

Comment: Hi Tab, I have added the examples of data... however, I wasn't sure how to add them, so I added them as code snippets which is not the way, I am sure.  Sorry!

Comment: I have also changed my query to include what you wrote , in case I have done something in error.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid not.  My suggestion isn't working the way I expected, apparently, and the only way I'd be able to figure out why is to be able to investigate the data in all of the tables involved.   But there are a lot of them, and even if you could post them all, I'd never be able to find the time to do it.

Comment: Thanks Tab, I appreciate your help on this.. It seems I won't be able to get this answer here.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you add another table to your Joins with

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT Filteredcbt_geographicarea.cbt_geographicareaid, string_agg(Filteredcbt_geographicarea.cbt_name, ', ') AS City_List
        FROM Filteredcbt_geographicarea
        GROUP BY 1) City_List_Lookup ON City_List_Lookup.cbt_geographicareaid = Filteredcbt_cbt_project_cbt_geographicarea.cbt_geographicareaid
```

Using this table, you can compare the concatenated Cities to the parameter entered.

So your where clause becomes:

```
City_List_Lookup.City_List = (@City)
```

By concatenating the various cities together, you can look for situations where the entire list consists of only one city.

Comment: Appreciate I've answered a very old question here, but it was useful for me, so must be for someone else as well!